# How to make IOS apps on windows?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, virtual-machine

I don't know if this is the correct forum to post this on but I'll just do it. I want to make IOS apps on windows. I know that I could install a VM but my processor is not compatible with OSX. This is a pretty simple question that may have a complex answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Apple don't make this very easy at all. They actually *want* you to buy a Mac.

The development software they use for iOS development doesn't run on non-Mac boxes. You may be able to get it running *technically* (such as on a Hackintosh) but you'll be violating the OSX licence agreement.

Comment: Yeah it does.  You can use Hackintosh to install on a fairly standard PC.  It's OSX you need, not a Mac.

Comment: @trojanfoe, you need to look at the licence agreement for OSX. It specifically forbids running on non-Mac hardware. People running Hackintoshes are breaking the law.

Comment: I was referring to the technical possibilities of running OSX on a standard PC, not the legal possibilities.  Bottom line - you can do it.

Comment: @trojanfoe, fair enough, I'll clarify my answer.